# Laplace transform problem involving piecewise function - Could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems

I attempted to solve the following second-order differential equation using the Laplace transform method:

$$2y'' + 3y' + y = g(t)$$

with the initial conditions $y(0) = y'(0) = 0$.

The input function $g(t)$ is defined as follows:

$$g(t)=\begin{cases} t, & 4<t<5 \\ 0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

First, I applied the Laplace transform to both sides of the equation to obtain the transformed equation in the s-domain. Then, I rearranged the equation to solve for $Y(s)$, the Laplace transform of $y(t)$.

Next, I applied partial fraction decomposition to express the transformed equation in a simpler form. I found the inverse Laplace transform of each term using tables and formulas. However, the resulting solution did not match the expected value of $y(4.5) = 0.20438$.

I'm looking for guidance and suggestions on how to correctly solve this differential equation and find the accurate value of $y(4.5)$. If there are any alternative methods or insights that could be helpful, please share them with me.

Thank you for your assistance and expertise in advance!

Steps:

Step 1: Define the differential equation:
$$2y" + 3y' + y = g(t)$$

Step 2: Define the input function $g(t)$:
$$g(t)=\begin{cases} t, & 4<t<5 \\ 0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Step 3: Apply the Laplace transform to both sides of the differential equation. Use the following formulas:

$$L{y"} = s^2Y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0)$$
$$L{y'} = sY(s) - y(0)$$
$$L{y} = Y(s)$$

After applying the Laplace transform, the differential equation becomes:

$$2(s^2Y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0)) + 3(sY(s) - y(0)) + Y(s) = G(s)$$

Step 4: Apply the initial conditions:
$y(0) = 0$
$y'(0) = 0$

Substitute these initial conditions into the Laplace transformed equation.

Step 5: Substitute the Laplace transform of the input function $g(t)$ into the equation. Use the following formula for the Laplace transform of $g(t)$:

$$L(g(t)) = G(s) = 1/s^2 - (e^{-4s}/s^2) + (e^{-5s}/s^2)$$

For each interval of $g(t)$, substitute the corresponding Laplace transform into the equation.

$$Y(s)[2s^2 + 3s + 1] = 1/s^2 - (e^{-4s}/s^2) + (e^{-5s}/s^2)$$

$$Y(s) =\frac{1/s^2 - (e^{-4s}/s^2) + (e^{-5s}/s^2)}{2s^2 + 3s + 1}$$

Stuck at this point!

Comment: You are probably better off showing all your work, rather than writing a high-level overview of your attempt. That way people can see if/where you made an error.

Comment: updated post! Thank you very much for your feedback, I've never used the forum and I'm having trouble adding equations

Comment: One way to simplify things a bit is to realize that $y(t)=0$ is a valid solution up to $t=4$. So one can let $z(t)=y(t+4)$ to get a signal which “starts” at $t=0$ instead, rendering the solution a bit tidier.

Comment: Here is a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial

Comment: Your $G(s)$ is wrong, correct is
$$G(s)=\frac{e^{-4 s} (4 s+1)}{s^2}-\frac{e^{-5 s} (5 s+1)}{s^2}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your Laplace transform of $g$ si wrong. Since
$$g(t)=t(u(t-4)-u(t-5))=(t-4)u(t-4)+4u(t-4)-(t-5)u(t-5)-5u(t-5)$$
then
$$\mathcal{L}(g)(s)=\frac{e^{-4s}}{s^2}+\frac{4e^{-4s}}{s}
-\frac{e^{-5s}}{s^2}-\frac{5e^{-5s}}{s}
=\frac{e^{-4s}(4s+1)}{s^2}-\frac{e^{-5s}(5s+1)}{s^2}.$$
The next step is to compute the inverse Laplace transform of
$$Y(s)=\frac{e^{-4s}(4s+1)-e^{-5s}(5s+1)}{s^2(2s^2 + 3s + 1)}
=e^{-4s}\frac{4s+1}{s^2(2 s + 1) (s + 1)}-e^{-5s}\frac{5s+1}{s^2(2 s + 1) (s + 1)}
.$$
Find the inverse transform of the rational functions
$$\frac{4s+1}{s^2(2 s + 1) (s + 1)}\quad \text{and}\quad \frac{5s+1}{s^2(2 s + 1) (s + 1)}$$
using Partial Fraction Decomposition and then apply time shifting.

Comment: Dear Robert, Thank you for your help and support on the forum. I have identified the error in the Laplace transform of g(t) and corrected it.

Comment: @GuilhermeMello Well done!